# How to set project template location in New Project window in TemplateData element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, project-template

I'm creating a new project template as a Visual Studio extension project and want it to be displayed in my custom group, that does exist before project template is installed, under **Visual C#** node.

[image]

I was hoping it is possible to setup project template location in it's `.vstemplate` file TemplateData section. I've tried to set `ProjectSubType` value, `TemplateGroupID`, `NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp` but it doesn't work. When Experimental instance of visual studio starts the project template is always in **Visual C#** group but not in **Visual C#/My Group**. ProjectSubType doesn't work even if My Group already exists but [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy7dh5te.aspx) says it should be created in subgroup. **How can I set project template location in TemplateData section?**

Answer (score 1):

Custom templates do not include a subdirectory for localized templates. You can change the default directory for custom templates in the Options dialog box, under Environment\Projects and Solutions.

I often add a folder manually and then copy the zip file, for example, I create a folder called "My Group" under the folder C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#.

And then create a simple Console app called Jack and export this project template, I didn't select this option.
[image]

Then I copy the Jack.zip to the above My Group folder. Re-open the VS, I will get this project template under the My Group folder.

[image]

This is the default .vstemplate file in my side:

```
    <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>Jack</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="Jack.csproj" File="Jack.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.config">App.config</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Program.cs">Program.cs</ProjectItem>
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to manually copy installed template. I export my template as a Visual Studio extension. And after I build VSIX file and install my extension I want my template to be in place without any manual manipulations.

Comment: If so, can it create the new folder "My Group" in the default project template folder? Can it copy the zip file to the created folder in your VSIX project?

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to create folder and copy installed .zip template file with C# code? Is it considered a good practice? Aren't there some built in methods? And if so ... Where should I handle this "Installation Completed" event?